# MongoDB High Avg. Flush Time - Write Heavy

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with approximately 4 million documents and around 5-6GB database size. The machine has 10GB of RAM, and free only reports around 3.7GB in use. The database is used for a video game related ladder (rankings) website, separated by region.

It's a fairly write heavy operation, but still gets a significant number of reads as well. We use an updater which queries an outside source every hour or two. This updater then processes the records and updates documents on the database. The updater only processes one region at a time (see previous paragraph), so approximately 33% of the database is updated.

When the updater runs, and for the duration that it runs, the average flush time spikes up to around 35-40 seconds, and we experience general slowdowns with other queries. The updater is RAN on a SEPARATE MACHINE and only queries MongoDB at the end, when all the data has been retrieved and processed from the third party.

Some people have suggested slowing down the number of updates, or only updating players who have changed, but the problem comes down to rankings. Since we support ties between players, we need to pre-calculate the ranks - so if only a few users have actually changed ranks, we still need to update the rest of the users ranks accordingly. At least, that was the case with MySQL - I'm not sure if there is a good solution with MongoDB for ranking ~800K->1.2 million documents while supporting ties.

My question is: how can we improve the flush and slowdown we're experiencing? Why is it spiking so high? Would disabling journaling (to take some load off the i/o) help, as data loss isn't something I'm worried about as the database is updated frequently regardless?

Server status: http://pastebin.com/w1ETfPWs

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/

Comment: I've added a link to server status.

Comment: Disabling journal will help to some extent, when the server is very busy. But this won't be very much effective. MongoDB by default flushes all the dirty pages every 60 secs and when 33% of data is updated that means kind of all pages (~ GBs of pages) are dirty, so I don't think 35-40 sec is a very big number. In my opinion, the design logic has to be re considered, as the above method won't scale.

Comment: I'm not very sure what to do. It's vital that the rank and row (rank, which includes ties, and row which is the actual row number) are updated whenever anyone's data changes. I think it could be possible to track changes and only update the rank for players that are effected as a result, but outside of that I don't have many ideas for what to do.

Right now everything is in one collection. Would separating collections out and updating rank data on a separate collection (fewer & smaller indexes?) have any effect? I'd have to run multiple read queries for each look-up, but could that work?

Comment: Let's say my data didn't all fit in memory. Would a significant number of updates to documents which weren't in memory cause the flush behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: So some third party lets you full scan their db every 2 hours? Thats brutal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any disk statistics, I am of the opinion that you are saturating your disks.

This can be checked with `iostat -xmt 2`, and checking the `%util` column.

Please don't disable journalling - you will only cause more issues later down the line when your machine crashes.

Separating collections will have no effect. Separating databases may, but if you're IO bound, this will do nothing to help you.

**Options**

If I am correct, and your disks are saturated, adding more disks in a RAID 10 configuration will vastly help performance and durability - more so if you separate the journal off to an SSD.

Assuming that this machine is a single server, you can setup a replicaset and send your read queries there. This should help you a fair bit, but not as much as the disks.

Comment: Let's say RAID 10 is out of reach at the moment. Would I see a significant performance increase in moving both the DB and journal to an SSD? We're currently rocking hybrid drives, but it seems like the idea behind caching with those would work better if we weren't randomly accessing any or all parts of our dataset fairly often.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. MongoDB isn't designed for ranking large ladders in real time, at least not quickly.

Use something like Redis, Redis have something called a "Sorted List" designed just for this job, with it you can have 100 millions entries and still fetch the 5000000th to 5001000th at sub millisecond speed.

From the official site ([Redis - Sorted sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)):

> **Sorted sets**
>
> **With sorted sets you can add, remove, or update elements in a very fast way** (in a time proportional to the logarithm of the number of elements). Since elements are taken in order and not ordered afterwards, you can also get ranges by score or by rank (position) in a very fast way. **Accessing the middle of a sorted set is also very fast**, so you can use Sorted Sets as a smart list of non repeating elements where you can quickly access everything you need: elements in order, fast existence test, fast access to elements in the middle!
>
> In short with sorted sets you can do a lot of tasks with great performance that are really hard to model in other kind of databases.
>
> **With Sorted Sets you can**:
>
> **Take a leader board in a massive online game, where every time a new score is submitted you update it using ZADD. You can easily take the top users using ZRANGE, you can also, given an user name, return its rank in the listing using ZRANK. Using ZRANK and ZRANGE together you can show users with a score similar to a given user. All very quickly.**
>
> Sorted Sets are often used in order to index data that is stored inside Redis. For instance if you have many hashes representing users, you can use a sorted set with elements having the age of the user as the score and the ID of the user as the value. So using ZRANGEBYSCORE it will be trivial and fast to retrieve all the users with a given interval of ages.
>
> Sorted Sets are probably the most advanced Redis data types, so take some time to check the full list of Sorted Set commands to discover what you can do with Redis!

Comment: So sorry, just discovered that I accidentally down voted this answer. For some reason so stops me undoing that unless the answer is edited. Can you do some random edit and I will remove my accidental down vote?